# Color an excel cell based on a minimum number value

Tags: excel

I am wondering: I have a group of cells in excel in which I have numbers, and I am using the MIN command to find the lowest number between these cells. I would like to have a cell next to the one displaying the lowest number then display a block of text and a cell color based on which of these cells has the lowest number, so I can basically show a "winner" of which number is the lowest in the data set. Is this possible?

So essentially it looks like:

1   2   3  (this cell shows 1 since it is the lowest) (this cell would look at the lowest value cell, and format the cell to be a certain color and have a certain text based on which had the lowest number)

I feel like this is an IF statement, but I cannot work out the proper way to do it.

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 =IF(A1=MIN($A$1:$A$5), "Winner","Loser")
```

And use conditional Formatting for the highlight based on cell with text contents